# Make WPF Listview adhere to the Windows theme

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, themes

I am an experienced coder who is trying to learn C# and WPF. Now, I am a bit of a stickler for detail, and I want to make sure my applications blend in with the rest of the user interface. However, I cannot seem to get this done using a ListView. My setup is simple - add a `ListView` to my window, bind to an `ObservableCollection` of my choice, and run the application.

The result is that the items pop up just fine (be it without meaningful contents). However, the selection rectangle on a ListView is always the dark blue that throws me back to the pre-XP days as opposed to the neater themed selection you have using the default Windows 7 visual style. To see that kind of selection in action, just select a file in explorer, or for another example look in the Programs and Features in the Control Panel. That looks nice and slick.

How can I get WPF to properly theme my ListView depending on my user settings? I don't want to reinvent the entire selection code and add tons of styling and doodahs like that - I want a plain Windows application that looks okay. The button works fine, textboxes work fine, comboboxes look fine, etc. It's just the ListView that looks totally crap.

**Edit:** I have no problems using another (very, very preferably not a thirdparty) control if required, but I do want a list of items that looks native and I approach a layout similar to the Tiles option in Explorer for each selected item (icon, desc, extra line of info). Vertical scrolling only is what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a ListView with ListView.View set to a GridView then you get a pretty similar look as Windows 7 explorer. (Atleast in my opinion, or is this the look you're talking about?). It also follows the active theme

Example 1. ListView with GridView to the right. Selection active

[image]

Example 2. ListView with GridView to the right. Selection inactive

[image]

Example 3. Using High Contrast Theme #2

[image]

Comment: Oh holy cow, so _that_ is the trick. I've been looking a whole damn day for this kind of effect. My only dislike is that something is off about the color - the WPF variety seems to have gone nuts with gamma or saturation or something like it. Shinier? I don't know what to call it; you can see it quite well on your example. Happen to know a fix for that? (My goal still is to look as native as possible.)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the first time I saw it too:) No idea why they didn't use the exact same colors as in explorer. Sorry, I don't no a fix for it either. I'm afraid your only option is to create your own colors and use them istead but that's hardly worth it.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for answering a question I've been googling to find a solution to all day.